# Testing responsive design

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsiveness

I'm working on a website using HTML, CSS and JS, and I use Bootstrap to make it responsive. 
I need to test it to see how it looks on different screen sizes.
How should I test it? 
Should i use Google devtools or some other smartphone emulator?

Thanks!

Comment: Just open it in your browser and make the window smaller? :D

Comment: Noticed scrollbars when I tried that :/ I'm gonna try siobhan's solution

Comment: So? Responsive design isn't just for mobile devices, it's also relevant for people on computers with lower resolutions, be it due to using an ancient monitor or they have vision problems and need everything to be bigger. They get scrollbars.

Comment: OK man thanks, I'll see how to cope with that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are various browser tools to test responsive page.

1. For **chrome** - https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/browser-resize/pnmdcoaajafdppfpioijldebfbpogopn?hl=en-GB
2. For Firefox try "ctrl+shift+M". It will turn browser screen re-sizable. Using drop-down on left-top specific height-width can be defined.

Answer (score 0):

Mitch, if you have it save, you can open it on a normal browser e.g. Chrome or Firefox and test it there (control + o and select the file from your computer). Great thing about HTML and web design is that you only need an editor and a browser to test before it is published

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply, I'm aware that I can open the site and see how it runs, but I'm going to see it on my 17" screen. Will your solution help me see it as it'll appear on a 5" device?

Comment: use chrome and enable Emulation

Comment: Thank you! Sorry. I'm new to this.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that chrome has an option where you can set different size parameters for this very reason.

[This plugin should surfice here](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/responsive-web-design-tes/objclahbaimlfnbjdeobicmmlnbhamkg?hl=en)

Comment: Just as user3807099 suggested, thanks mate!

Comment: I didn't check that link, no problem. Good luck!